# What defines an "avid user"?

Tags: support, area-51, users, site-stats

On area51.SE and SE, you can see the stats of all sites. I'm curious about one thing: what defines an "avid user"? Reputation count? Activity on the site?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An "avid user" is a user with at least 200 reputation. That's what the on-hover tooltip says.

[image: "Users with 200 or more reputation"]

Comment: Thanks, I'm running off a mobile phone, so I wasn't able to get the on-hover tooltip.